# round edges corner on a QWidget in PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, pyside, pyqt5

I have made a greadient QWidget in PyQt4 but instead of sharp edges I want to have round edges, is it possible to do in pyqt ?

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import sys

class ControlBar(QtGui.QWidget):
    """ docstring for ControlBar"""
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ControlBar, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(440, 100)
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setWindowTitle("QLinearGradient Vertical Gradient ")
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        self.buildUi()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.offset = event.pos()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        try:
              x=event.globalX()
              y=event.globalY()
              x_w = self.offset.x()
              y_w = self.offset.y()
              self.move(x-x_w, y-y_w)
        except: pass   

    def paintEvent(self, ev):
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        gradient = QtGui.QLinearGradient(QtCore.QRectF(self.rect()).topLeft(),QtCore.QRectF(self.rect()).bottomLeft())
        gradient.setColorAt(0.0, QtCore.Qt.black)
        gradient.setColorAt(0.4, QtCore.Qt.gray)
        gradient.setColorAt(0.7, QtCore.Qt.black)
        painter.setBrush(gradient)
        painter.drawRoundedRect(0, 0, 440, 100, 20.0, 20.0)

    def buildUi(self):
        self.hoelayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.openBtn = RoundEdgeButton("Hello")
        self.backBtn = RoundEdgeButton()
        self.pausBtn = RoundEdgeButton()
        self.nextBtn = RoundEdgeButton()
        self.hoelayout.addStretch(1)
        self.hoelayout.addWidget(self.openBtn)
        self.hoelayout.addStretch(1)
        self.hoelayout.addWidget(self.backBtn)
        self.hoelayout.addStretch(1)
        self.hoelayout.addWidget(self.pausBtn)
        self.hoelayout.addStretch(1)
        self.hoelayout.addWidget(self.nextBtn)
        self.hoelayout.addStretch(1)
        self.setLayout(self.hoelayout)

class RoundEdgeButton(QtGui.QPushButton):
    """ docstring for RoundEdgeButton"""
    def __init__(self,text=None, parent=None):
        super(RoundEdgeButton, self).__init__(parent)

        if text:
            self.setText(text)

    def paintEvent(self, ev):
        btnPaint = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        btnGradient = QtGui.QLinearGradient(QtCore.QRectF(self.rect()).topLeft(), QtCore.QRectF(self.rect()).bottomLeft())
        btnGradient.setColorAt(0.8, QtCore.Qt.black)
        btnGradient.setColorAt(0.1, QtCore.Qt.gray)
        btnGradient.setColorAt(0.8, QtCore.Qt.black)
        btnPaint.setBrush(btnGradient)
        btnPaint.drawRoundedRect(self.rect(), 100.0, 100.0)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = ControlBar()
    win.show()
    win.raise_()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Here is how it looks like now

[image: Squished buttons wanted round]

Comment: I've updated the answer for semi-transparent buttons

Comment: Change `btnPaint.drawRoundedRect(0, 0, 50, 50, 100.0, 100.0)` for `btnPaint.drawRoundedRect(self.rect(), 100.0, 100.0)`

Comment: we are missing something, why would they get squished in the middle to form oval, I understand rect() is QRect(0, 0 , 75, 32) but changing this value entering manually to drawRoundedRect enlarges the button but it still gets cut at the middle...

Comment: What if you try with less round radius, like `btnPaint.drawRoundedRect(self.rect(), 10.0, 10.0)`?

Comment: You can add `def sizeHint(self): return QtCore.QSize(100,27)` to your `RoundEdgeButton` class.

Comment: well I think something from the `ControlBar` class is cropping the buttons. however now I have managed to have different shape other than round..

Comment: Well, if you found my answer useful, could you accept it?

Comment: i will do that for sure when i get round buttons :-)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44010/discussion-between-xndrme-and-san)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can paint the area of the widget by yourself using `QPainter.drawRoundedRect`:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import * 
from PyQt4.QtCore import * 
import sys


class MyRoundWidget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super(MyRoundWidget,self).__init__(master)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setWindowTitle("QLinearGradient Vertical Gradient ")
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)


    def paintEvent(self, ev):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.begin(self)
        gradient = QLinearGradient(QRectF(self.rect()).topLeft(),QRectF(self.rect()).bottomLeft())
        gradient.setColorAt(0.0, Qt.black)
        gradient.setColorAt(0.4, Qt.gray)
        gradient.setColorAt(0.7, Qt.black)
        painter.setBrush(gradient)
        painter.drawRoundedRect(self.rect(), 10.0, 10.0)
        painter.end()


def main():    

    app     = QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = MyRoundWidget()    

    widget.show()
    widget.raise_()



    sys.exit(app.exec_())
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And for making the buttons semi-transparent do this:

```
self.setStyleSheet("""
        QPushButton{
        opacity: 50;            
        background-color: rgba(204,204,204,10);
        }
        """)
```

Change `10` for the value you like between `0` and `255`.

If you just want round buttons (not round rectangle buttons) replace `btnPaint.drawRoundedRect(self.rect(), 100.0, 100.0)` for `btnPaint.drawEllipse(10,10,self.width()-10, self.height()-10)`

Comment: is it this black magic causing this `QPainter::begin: A paint device can only be painted by one painter at a time.` in terminal ?

Comment: @san yes, Like I said the right way of doing it is sub-classing `QWidget`, I will refactor the answer later :)

Comment: Still getting the `QPainter::begin: Painter already active` message, I'm  wondering why?

Comment: yes, I have added buttons too but the buttons are sharp corners look ugly, I am going to update code above in the question

Comment: I have achieved a point where the buttons don't show up properly, I reimplemented the QPushButton, and made them round as well, just like you did with the widget but the position and gradient is not showing properly.. updating code again.

Answer (score 2):

painter = QPainter(self)
if construct the QPainter object, then it will be unnecessary to call the begin() and end().